# I wanted to analyse some data using numpy but an error keeps popping out when i execute my code

Tags: python

..how do i solve this, i even tried installing panda packages

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-59ab05e21164> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import pandas as pd

~\pandas.py in <module>
     21 
     22 
---> 23 df1 = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data1, columns = ['id', 'Feature1', 'Feature2'])
     24 
     25 

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'DataFrame'
```

Comment: do you have a python file called `pandas.py`? If so then this may be the cause of the confusion, you should remove this so it doesn't interfere with the pandas module

Comment: the script you're running is called `pandas.py`, so `import pandas as pd` imports your module instead of the real pandas

Comment: i wasn't aware of that, it did work (thanks @EdChum & @Dan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a **~\pandas.py** file which is been taken as the **pandas** module instead of the real installed one. Consider to rename that file.

Comment: I removed the pandas.py files , ran my code & didn't encounter errors  (THANK YOU VERY MUCH)